# Cannot access the parameter of a Menu.param from a Lift Snippet

Tags: scala, web-applications, lift

I'm trying to extract the parameter from a Lift Menu.param within a snippet so that I can use it to create a named Comet. However, I get a NullPointerException when I try to pass the parameter to the snippet using SnippetDisptach in my Boot.scala, as suggested here:
http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.web.lift/44299

I've created the Menu item as follows:

```
object AnItemPage {
// create a parameterized page
  def menu = Menu.param[Item]("Item", "Item",
                                s => fetchItem(s), item => item._id.toString) / "item"

  private def fetchItem(s:String) : Box[Item] = synchronized {
          ItemDAO.findById(ObjectId.massageToObjectId(s)) 
  }

}
```

I've added the menu to SiteMap. I've also created a Snippet which I would like to pick up the Item parameter. (I'm using fmpwizard's InsertNamedComet library here):

```
 class AddCometItemPage(boxedItem: Box[Item]) extends InsertNamedComet with DispatchSnippet{
     val item : Item = boxedItem.openOr(null)
     override lazy val name= "comet_item_" + item._id.toString
     override lazy val cometClass= "UserItemCometActor"

     def dispatch = null
    }
```

My next step is to crate an instance of this class as demonstrated by David Pollak here:
http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.web.lift/44299

This is what I have added to my Boot.scala:

```
LiftRules.snippetDispatch.append {
  case "item_page" => new AddCometItemPage(AnItemPage.menu.currentValue)
}
```

My item.html references this snippet:

```
 <div class="lift:item_page">
```

I get the following null pointer exception when I compile and run this:

```
Exception occurred while processing /item/5114eb4044ae953cf863b786

Message: java.lang.NullPointerException
net.liftweb.sitemap.Loc$class.siteMap(Loc.scala:147)
net.liftweb.sitemap.Menu$ParamMenuable$$anon$9.siteMap(Menu.scala:170)
net.liftweb.sitemap.Loc$class.allParams(Loc.scala:123)
net.liftweb.sitemap.Menu$ParamMenuable$$anon$9.allParams(Menu.scala:170)
net.liftweb.sitemap.Loc$class.net$liftweb$sitemap$Loc$$staticValue(Loc.scala:87)
net.liftweb.sitemap.Menu$ParamMenuable$$anon$9.net$liftweb$sitemap$Loc$$staticValue(Menu.scala:170)
net.liftweb.sitemap.Loc$$anonfun$paramValue$2.apply(Loc.scala:85)
net.liftweb.sitemap.Loc$$anonfun$paramValue$2.apply(Loc.scala:85)
net.liftweb.common.EmptyBox.or(Box.scala:646)
net.liftweb.sitemap.Loc$class.paramValue(Loc.scala:85)
net.liftweb.sitemap.Menu$ParamMenuable$$anon$9.paramValue(Menu.scala:170)
net.liftweb.sitemap.Loc$$anonfun$currentValue$3.apply(Loc.scala:114)
net.liftweb.sitemap.Loc$$anonfun$currentValue$3.apply(Loc.scala:114)
net.liftweb.common.EmptyBox.or(Box.scala:646)
net.liftweb.sitemap.Loc$class.currentValue(Loc.scala:114)
net.liftweb.sitemap.Menu$ParamMenuable$$anon$9.currentValue(Menu.scala:170)
bootstrap.liftweb.Boot$$anonfun$lift$8.apply(Boot.scala:107)
bootstrap.liftweb.Boot$$anonfun$lift$8.apply(Boot.scala:106)
net.liftweb.util.NamedPF$$anonfun$applyBox$1.apply(NamedPartialFunction.scala:97)
net.liftweb.util.NamedPF$$anonfun$applyBox$1.apply(NamedPartialFunction.scala:97)
net.liftweb.common.Full.map(Box.scala:553)
net.liftweb.util.NamedPF$.applyBox(NamedPartialFunction.scala:97)
net.liftweb.http.LiftRules.snippet(LiftRules.scala:711)
net.liftweb.http.LiftSession$$anonfun$net$liftweb$http$LiftSession$$findSnippetInstance$1.apply(LiftSession.scala:1506)
net.liftweb.http.LiftSession$$anonfun$net$liftweb$http$LiftSession$$findSnippetInstance$1.apply(LiftSession.scala:1506)
net.liftweb.common.EmptyBox.or(Box.scala:646)
net.liftweb.http.LiftSession.net$liftweb$http$LiftSession$$findSnippetInstance(LiftSession.scala:1505)
net.liftweb.http.LiftSession$$anonfun$locateAndCacheSnippet$1$1$$anonfun$apply$88.apply(LiftSession.scala:1670)
net.liftweb.http.LiftSession$$anonfun$locateAndCacheSnippet$1$1$$anonfun$apply$88.apply(LiftSession.scala:1669)
```

Has anybody any idea where I'm going wrong? I've not been able to find a lot of information on Menu.param.

Thank you very much for your help.

f

Comment: Hey fin :) Which version of Lift/Scala are you running? 2.4 or 2.9 or 2.5-SNAPSHOT on 2.10 or something like that? :)

Comment: Hi Franz. I'm using Scala 2.9.1 with lift 2.5-M2. Thanks very much for looking at this!

Comment: Hm, this behavior is really weird. Have you tried the lift google groups? My guess is that it's a bug, but please ask in the groups first before opening an issue. Sadly my lift netty port isnt far enough to test it with that. :)

Comment: Cheers Franz. I'll post on google groups. I'll also give jcerns workaround a go below. Thanks, Fin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have never tried what you are doing, so I am not sure the best way to accomplish it. The way you are using the Loc Param, you are extracting a variable from a URL pattern. In your case, `http://server/item/ITEMID` where `ITEMID` is the string representation of an Item, and which is the value that gets passed to the `fetchItem` function. The function call will not have a value if you just arbitrarily call it, and from what I can see you are requesting a value that is not initialized.

I would think there are two possible solutions. The first would be to use [`S.location`](http://scala-tools.org/mvnsites/liftweb-2.4/#net.liftweb.http.S) instead of `AnItemPage.menu.currentValue`. It will return a `Box[Loc[Any]]` representing the `Loc` that is currently being accessed (with the parameters set). You can use that `Loc` to retrive `currentValue` and set your parameter.

The other option would be to instantiate the actor in your snippet. Something like this:

**item.html**

```
   <div data-lift="AnItemPage">
     <div id="mycomet"></div>
   </div>
```

And then in your AnItemPage snippet, something like this:

```
class AnItemPage(item: Item) {
  def render = "#mycomet" #> new AddCometItemPage(item).render 
}
```

I haven't tested either of those, so they'll probably need some tweaking. Hopefully it will give you a general idea.

Comment: Thanks jcern. I've tried the second idea above but unfortunately I cannot pass an Item object to the snippet. I'll test out your first suggestion now.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why can't you pass an Item to the snippet? Generally, that would be handled by lift. Lift will look for a snippet with a constructor that accepts the object extracted from the URL. The  full code to the example I think you were modeling after is available here for reference: https://github.com/dpp/simply_lift/tree/master/samples/shopwithme/src/main/webapp which has a full example of it.

Comment: Passing the item to the snippet works. I think my initial problem was that I didn't register the menu with SiteMap. Thanks.